# Django: Prepopulate Formset with ManyToMany Relationship and additional Fields

Tags: django, many-to-many, formset

I have two models with an M2M relationship and extra fields: A menu is a compilation of many courses (i.e. dishes). The M2M relationship is reflected in `MenuItem` class/table. `MenuItem` has two additional fields: `course_type` (i.e. starter, appetizer, etc.) and `course_position` (to keep track of the position).

**models.py**

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator_id_menu', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    menu_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name=_('menu name'), help_text=_('i.e. saturday night fajita night'))
    menu_description = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', verbose_name=_('menu description'), help_text=_('this menu will blow your mind...'))
    menu_item = models.ManyToManyField(Course, through='MenuItem', blank=True)
    

class Course(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator_id_course', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text=_('give your creation a nice name!'))
    course_description = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', verbose_name=_('course description'), help_text=_('give your creation a brief description!'))

    
class MenuItem(models.Model):    
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('menu name'))
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('course name'))
    course_type = models.CharField(choices=CourseType.choices, max_length=3, verbose_name=_('course type'))
    course_position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('course position'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    course_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MenuItem.CourseType.choices)
    course_description = forms.Textarea()

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['course_name', 'course_description']   

CourseFormset = modelformset_factory(Course,
                                     form=CourseForm,
                                     extra=0)
```

I can prepopulating the ModelFormset with the data from `Course`, but don't know, how to correctly access the `MenuItem` instance. That is why, my `views.py` misses the `request.POST` processing.

**views.py**

```
def update_menu_with_courses(request, pk):    
    context = {}
    menu_instance = Menu.objects.get(id=pk)

    # initializing forms
    menu_form = MenuCreationForm(request.POST or None, instance=menu_instance)
    menu_items = menu_instance.menu_item.all()

    course_formset = CourseFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=menu_items, prefix='course')

    context['menu_form'] = menu_form
    context['course_formset'] = course_formset

    return render(request, 'menus/update_menu_courses.html', context)
```

My question:

- How do I prepopulate a ModelFormset with M2M relationship and extra fields in the M2M Table.
- How do I update the M2M extra fields in `MenuItem`